# Can't open a netcdf4 file using ncplot

Tags: netcdf4

I am trying to open a netcdf4 file using ncplot but it gives the following errors for several variables

> UserWarning: More than one y coordinate present for variable  "variable".

the netcdf4 has the following format

> dimensions(sizes): number_of_flashes(126), number_of_groups(3416), number_of_events(10561), number_of_time_bounds(2), number_of_field_of_view_bounds(2), number_of_wavelength_bounds(2)
> variables(dimensions): int32 event_id(number_of_events), int16 event_time_offset(number_of_events), int16 event_lat(number_of_events), int16 event_lon(number_of_events), int16 event_energy(number_of_events), int32 event_parent_group_id(number_of_events), int32 group_id(number_of_groups), int16 group_time_offset(number_of_groups), int16 group_frame_time_offset(number_of_groups), float32 group_lat(number_of_groups), float32 group_lon(number_of_groups), int16 group_area(number_of_groups), int16 group_energy(number_of_groups), int16 group_parent_flash_id(number_of_groups), int16 group_quality_flag(number_of_groups), int16 flash_id(number_of_flashes), int16 flash_time_offset_of_first_event(number_of_flashes), int16 flash_time_offset_of_last_event(number_of_flashes), int16 flash_frame_time_offset_of_first_event(number_of_flashes), int16 flash_frame_time_offset_of_last_event(number_of_flashes), float32 flash_lat(number_of_flashes), float32 flash_lon(number_of_flashes), int16 flash_area(number_of_flashes), int16 flash_energy(number_of_flashes), int16 flash_quality_flag(number_of_flashes), float64 product_time(), float64 product_time_bounds(number_of_time_bounds), float32 lightning_wavelength(), float32 lightning_wavelength_bounds(number_of_wavelength_bounds), float32 group_time_threshold(), float32 flash_time_threshold(), float32 lat_field_of_view(), float32 lat_field_of_view_bounds(number_of_field_of_view_bounds), int32 goes_lat_lon_projection(), int32 event_count(), int32 group_count(), int32 flash_count(), float32 percent_navigated_L1b_events(), int8 yaw_flip_flag(), float32 nominal_satellite_subpoint_lat(), float32 nominal_satellite_height(), float32 nominal_satellite_subpoint_lon(), float32 lon_field_of_view(), float32 lon_field_of_view_bounds(number_of_field_of_view_bounds), float32 percent_uncorrectable_L0_errors(), int32 algorithm_dynamic_input_data_container(), int32 processing_parm_version_container(), int32 algorithm_product_version_container()

I still didnt try anything because I couldn't find what is the cause

Comment: Is the data from GEOS Lighting Mapper (GLM)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that ncplot is not a universal instrument. It requires the file to have a specific structure which GLM files do not have. What do you want to achieve with this file?